# Reading stdin line by line

Tags: php, stdin

I am reading STDIN with fgets but problem is, that I need to read one single line even if I copy-paste content to STDIN.

```
imput example:
1st line
2nd line
3rd line


code:
while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets(STDIN))) {
echo $line;
}
```

This script will put all there 3 lines in to variable $line, but I need to put only "1st line" to $line. How to do it? sorry for my bad english

Comment: split it by \n separator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [php.net](http://www.php.net) this should work

```
$line=trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

Otherwise you could use this

```
$handle=$fopen('file.ext');
$line=fgets($handle);
fclose($handle);
```